# How to solve this error: E1042: Export can only be used in vim9script and correctly set Java Path and Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I tried to run maven and I got the message: -bash: mvn: command not found.
Then I followed instructions to set the Java path as follows:

$ vim .bash_profile

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

$ source .bash_profile

But when I write the command export I get the message: "E1042: Export can only be used in vim9script". How could I solve this? I'm new to this and not very profi with terminal.

Comment: Did you install Maven? It does not come bundled with Java.

Comment: Yes, I did install it...

Comment: Where did you install it? The `mvn` executable is not found in JAVA_HOME, nor does it go on the CLASSPATH. It goes on the PATH, like any other executable you may want to run from the shell.

Comment: I used "brew install maven" (on a mac). As far as I understood, it may have been installed in the zsh shell ad what I'm trying to do is to set the path to the bash shell... Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes, you need to set PATH in your bash configuration to include the Homebrew bin.